# Umbraco - Changing media type

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco7

Is there a way to change a media type after it has been created, ideally through c# code, in Umbraco?

Migration by creating a new media node with the new type and migrating images below that media type is turning out more and more problematic, due to references.

Is there a nice way to change, say a folder, to a custom media type?

I am using Umbraco 7 and am looking to perform this migration on the Saved event on the content or media service in the App_Code folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to do something very similar with document templates. You have two options - either you can change the media type, or you could create a new media with the correct type, copy properties over and destroy the old one.  There should be plenty of code samples to do that but shout if you get stuck

You should just be able to add an event handler in the app_code folder to fire on save

Comment: If you do fix it, remember to post your code to help others :)

Comment: So I tried that, but when I was almost finished implementing it (typical time to realise), duplicating images and placing them in the new media type folder was messing up any references to those images (and there are a ton of references) which is why I am avoiding using the GUI to do it. You mentioned changing the media type... would something along the lines of this work? folder.ContentType.Alias = "newMediaTypeAlias" ? or is the way media types assigned more complex than just using the alias?

Comment: I would suggest try it - I don't honestly know, but if you pasted the snippet you used, I could take a look. I'd suggest either setting either the MediaTypeID or MediaType and saving the Media object would probably be the way to go rather than the Alias, but I'm not certain either would work without trying it

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar need of changing the mediaType associated with nodes. There is the option in the context menu of the Content tree, but nothing similar in the Media tree GUI. Have you found a good way to make this happen and refresh all of the cache/xml associated with them?

I do have suggestion if you went with the route of creating new media nodes to get the new type in place. You mention in a comment, duplicating images to place them as children in the new folder and this messing up references to the images. There is a "Move node" option in the GUI, which will keep the same nodeID for your child images, and thus any references to them. Programatically, I think this would involve updating attributes for the image node, and making sure trees.config gets refreshed.

```
<ChildImage id="4099" parentID="4098" level="4" creatorID="2" sortOrder="0" createDate="2014-10-16T10:32:07" updateDate="2015-05-05T14:32:15" nodeName="Cutler - 101" urlName="my-image" path="-1,3285,3287,4098,4099" isDoc="" nodeType="2887" writerName="admin" writerID="2" version="03d9a03d-4cc5-4e27-b9ff-6651362e264b" template="0" nodeTypeAlias="ChildImage">
```

The attributes I believe that would need changing are parentID and path

Comment: trees.config is only used to register and edit the trees in each section and their attributes - ordering for example.  You may mean the umbraco.config file which is the xml cache for published content - that shouldn't be edited either - you need to edit add/update media nodes using the Umbraco Service Api to manipulate media items.

Comment: Thank, you for the clarification/details. There is absolutely and API function for 'move' in the [media service](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Management/Services/MediaService)

Comment: sure - but it won't help you in changing the MediaType.  For that, you need to edit the database records directly so that the media item points at the new MediaType - I would probably go and take a look at the existing code for changing the ContentType - that would give you a starting place for this kind of thing.